# iOS/xcode: didReceiveData empty when run on device but fine on simulator?

Tags: objective-c, json, api

I am developing an iphone app which is using an API.

On the '**simulator**' it works fine. On the '**device**' the api calls all run but response delegates all return EMPTY.

**LOG:**
**1)** `didReceiveData` returns (empty `NSData` i.e. <20>) below for **device**:

```
append data <20>
```

But this for **simulator**:

```
append data <dfgdf89fgd.....>
```

**2)** The `didReceiveResponse` I have below returns below for the **device** (set NSLog to monitor NSURLConnection object). Confused why this is not complete:

```
1 connection <NSURLConnection: 0x147a30>
```

But this for the **simulator**:

```
1 connection <NSURLConnection: 0x4b76ea0, http://api.site.com/search?id=111>
```

**3)** The `connectionDidFinishLoading` is below for **simulator**

```
DONE. Received Bytes: 1400
```

But below for **device**:

```
DONE. Received Bytes: 1
```

**My code:**
I have the below code inside an API file:

```
- (void)fetch: (NSString *)id{

    NSMutableData *receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];//initialised
   self.receivedData = receivedData;//set to available globally

   NSString *initialUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://api.site.com/search?id=%@",id];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:initialUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"Token token=\"apitoken\"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[request autorelease] delegate:self];

}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"1 connection %@",connection);
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [self.receivedData setLength: 0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

     NSLog(@"2 connection %@",connection);
     NSLog(@"append data %@",data);
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //TODO error handling for connection
    NSLog(@"Cannot Connect");
    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(apiFailed:)]) {
        [_delegate apiFailed:[error localizedDescription]];
    }

}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [self.receivedData length]);
    NSLog(@"FULL DATA: %@",self.receivedData);
}
```

The **simulator** and **device** (my iphone with provisioned profile on and working) are both running off the same Wifi (my home router).

**The API:**
The API returns a small amount of JSON and I have tested with a different set of JSON and both device and simulator return full JSON no problem, I only cant get it to work with THIS API. 
I even have the same JSON (the api returns) inside a different location and I can do the EXACT same request (with headers and authentication) and it works no problem for **device**. Strangely though the connection object still doesnt look right for the fake api server. On **device** `didReceiveResponse` has `1 connection <NSURLConnection: 0x1af600>` still and not with the connection url (but when run on **simulator** it has `1 connection <NSURLConnection: 0x8193fd0, http://test-server.com:81/api-data.json>`). This suggest that its a normal difference between **device** and **simulator** `NSURLCONNECTION` objects.
I feel it might be the authentication getting in the way but the API is completely open (assuming you have token) and works no problem with the simulator plus `didFailWithError` is not run..

I have declared the delegate methods inside the header file. 
No idea why the connection object as well as the data object would both be having problems.

**Alternative:**
I tried the below inside the fetch method instead of what I have already but it also works on **Simulator** but same thing happens on **Device**.

```
//NSURLCONN and NSDATA in response still return empty???
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL                                                                  
         URLWithString:@"http://api.site.com/search?id=111"]
         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
         timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"Token token=\"mytoken\"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I would appreciate ANY ideas on this.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For testing:

1. Remove caching from the request (it can do some really funny things).
2. Print out the HTTP status code in `connection:didReceiveResponse:`. Make sure you are getting 200 (you should always check the status code!)
3. Test the connection in some other REST client (plugins for most browsers exist).
4. Make sure the API is not "User-Agent" sensitive.
5. If "https" protocol is used, make sure the certificate is signed by a root authority known to the device.
6. Use the debugger to check that everything is working correctly (e.g. `url` is not `nil`, when the request is being created).
7. Are you sure you are using `Authorization` header correctly? Value `Token token="..."` seems strange.

Comment: (3) is done on Firefox RESTCLIENT and is fine. No https (5). The headers are same and work ok for simulator (4). Will try (2) now. How is best to do (1)?

Comment: @CraigTaub for 1 - set request cache policy to be NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

Comment: thanks...good idea checking status code, its returning `401 (unauthorized)` which is very strange as its 200 for simulator...(6) checking already, yep its correct and (7) same thing.

Comment: If 401 is returned, it will probably be a problem with the `Authorization` header but I think you already know it :) `NSLog` all the headers in the request might be a good idea.

Comment: yeah its a really wierd one as still returning 401 for device but 200 for simulator. Am speaking to API guys but will also nslog out my headers and report back

Comment: added `NSLog(@"%@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);` before NSUrlConnection...both device/simulation print 'Accept' and 'Authorization' looking identical :(

Comment: If you can talk to the API guys, they should be able to say why 401 is returned. If the URL and headers are the same, then it's strange. Maybe the server is checking the IP address or something. Or your request is not even reaching the server (some dns collision in your network or vpn?)

Comment: Ok. So turns out the api required www subdomain and was redirecting if it did not have it. Still not sure why simulator was working but least works now on device. Thanks for the help